# exercise on multivariate Ito's lemma + jumps (Poisson)

Tags: itos-lemma, jump-diffusion

Given the two jump-diffusions:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
dX_{1,t} &= a_1 dt + b_1 dW_t + c_1 dN_t(\lambda) \\
dX_{2,t} &= a_2 dt + b_2 dW'_t + c_2 dN_t(\lambda) \\
corr(dW,dW') &= \rho \\
dN & \mbox{: Poisson process, of intensity } \lambda 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which SDE 
$$df_t = ? $$
satisfies the function 
$$
f_t = f(X_{1,t}, X_{2,t}) \mbox{ ???}
$$ 
Thanks in advance for help and/or references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

Assuming the Poisson process $N_t$ is independent from the Brownian motions $(W_{1,t},W_{2,t})$, you'll have 
\begin{align}
df(X_{1,t},X_{2,t}) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{1,t}} dX_{1,t}^c 
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{2,t}} dX_{2,t}^c + \dots \\
&+ \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_{1,t}^2 } d\langle X_{1,t} \rangle_t^c + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_{2,t}^2} d\langle X_{2,t} \rangle_t^c + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_{1,t} \partial X_{2,t}} d\langle X_{1,t} X_{2,t} \rangle_t^c + \dots \\
&+ \left( f(X_{1,t},X_{2,t}) - f(X_{1,t^-},X_{2,t^-}) \right) dN_t 
\end{align}
where the superscript $c$ denotes the continuous part of the semi-martingales $(X_{i,t})_{t \geq 0}$ i.e.
$$ d X_{i,t}^c = a_i dt + b_i dW_{i,t},\,\,\, i=1,2$$
such that
$$ d\langle X_{i,t} \rangle_t^c = b_i^2 dt,\,\,\, i=1,2 $$
$$ d\langle X_{1,t}, X_{2,t} \rangle_t^c = \rho b_1 b_2 dt $$

**Remark 1** : All the derivatives above should be evaluated at $t^-$;

**Remark 2** : I've used the notation $\langle X \rangle_t$ to refer to the *optional* quadratic variation (sometimes denoted by $[ X ]_t$ in the literature) rather than *previsible* quadratic variation (previsible quadratic variation is the compensator of optional quadratic variation). In case the process has continuous paths the 2 concepts coincide but here it's not the case so I hope this clarifies things.

---

### Background

Consider a non-continuous semi-martingale $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ solution of
$$ dX_t = a dt + b dW_t + c dN_t $$
Anticipating on what comes next, we also introduce its *continuous counterpart* $(X_t^c)_{t \geq 0}$ verifying
$$ dX_t^c = a dt + bdW_t $$

In differential form, the generalised Itô formula for non-continuous semi-martingales reads (cf. equation (2) [in this great blog](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/) + demonstration),
\begin{align}
df(X_t) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} dX_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} d\langle X \rangle_t \dots \\
&+ \left( \underbrace{\left( f(X_t)-f(X_{t^-}) \right)}_{\Delta f(X_t)} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} \underbrace{c}_{\Delta X_t} -  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} \underbrace{c^2}_{\Delta X_t^2} \right) dN_t \tag{1} 
\end{align}

The quadratic variation of the non-continuous semi-martingale $(X_t)$ computes as 
$$ d\langle X \rangle_t =  b^2 dt + c^2 dN_t = d\langle X \rangle_t^c + c^2 dN_t $$ 
assuming the Poisson process is independent from the Brownian motion under our working probability space (cf. [section 15.4](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf)). Along with the definition of the SDE satisfied by $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ this result allows us to rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
df(X_t) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} \left(a dt + b dW_t + \cancel{c dN_t} \right) + \dots \\
&\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} \left( b^2 dt + \cancel{c^2 dN_t} \right) + \dots \\
&+ \left( (f(X_t)-f(X_{t^-}) \cancel{- \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} c} \cancel{-  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} c^2} \right) dN_t 
\end{align}

$$  df(X_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} dX_t^c + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} d\langle X_t\rangle_t^c + \left( f(X_t)-f(X_{t^-}) \right) dN_t $$

Now you can repeat the experiment starting from the multivariate counterpart of $(1)$ i.e.
\begin{align}
df(X_t) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} dX_t + \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y_t} dY_t + \dots \\
&\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} d\langle X \rangle_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y_t^2} d\langle Y \rangle_t  + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t Y_t} d\langle X, Y \rangle_t \dots  \\
&+ \left( \Delta f(X_t,Y_t) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t} \Delta X_t - \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y_t} \Delta Y_t \dots \\
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2} \Delta X_t^2 
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y_t^2} \Delta Y_t^2 - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t \partial Y_t } \Delta X_t \Delta Y_t \right) dN_t \tag{2} 
\end{align}
to end up on the above mentioned answer.